# Comparing a list against another val list Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that will string match and compare exactly between two strings in python 3, basically the second list is the validation so if any item in list1 isnt in list2 i want to throw an error out. If it makes any difference list1 is from a CSV file, ive managed to get the rows into the right places.

I'm fairly new and a bit lost.
EG:

```
list1 = ["a", "B", "AB"]
list2 = ["a","B","abc"]
```

So "AB" from list1 should shut down the program until the someone has fixed the CSV file because "AB" isnt in list2

```
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["b", "a"]
```

This should pass because they both are in both lists

list1 may have the same string multiple times, ive tried all i can think of.
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: do they need to have the same size or can one be larger than the other?

Comment: elethans answer below worked for me using sets, i wanted to be able to have the error checking grow as my CSV file did, but if something weird got into it then it would throw out errors

Answer (score 1):

Unlike e.g., JavaScript, you can compare lists with `==` in Python and potentially get back `True` even if they are not the same object:

```
In [1]: list1 = ["a", "B", "AB"]

In [2]: list2 = ["a","B","abc"]

In [3]: list1 == list2
Out[3]: False

In [4]: list3 = ["a", "B", "AB"]

In [5]: list1 == list3
Out[5]: True
```

If the lists may potentially be the same, but may not be in the same order, you can compare sorted lists.

```
In [6]: list4 == list1
Out[6]: False

In [7]: sorted(list4) == sorted(list1)
Out[7]: True
```

So you can do something like:

```
def same_list(l1, l2):
    return sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)
```

If you literally want to raise an error if the lists aren't equal, you could use `raise MyError` inside of the `same_list()` function, or use it if that function returns `False`.

> **list1 may have the same string multiple times**

If you want a situation like:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b"]
list2 = ["b", "a"]
```

to *not* raise an error, you could use `set()`:

```
set(list1) == set(list2)    # This will evaluate to True for the lists above
```

This will compare the unique elements of both lists, ignoring duplicates (also note that sorting is not necessary for sets).

Comment: Hey i actually found a different way to solve me own problem (at least for my use)
i made a key list, now when the info is fed in from the CSV file, the program uses a for loop to check if its in a list and throws an error out if it isnt in the key list... But thanks for your help man